# Store Fb user data in session and use in another activity android

Tags: java, android, facebook, session

i am using Facebook login, after successful login in Login Activity screen moves to Main Activity. i want to display Facebook user details in main activity like name, email, location, gender, fbid. i am storing the data in session with the help of `SharedPreferences`. Now i want to use the session values in my main activity. i am trying `HashMap` but its working for 2 values only. bellow is my login activity

```
fbloginbtn.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("Main", response.toString());
                                setProfileToView(object);
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,location");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();


                session.setFblogin(true);

                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

private void setProfileToView(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        try {
            String fbemail= jsonObject.getString("email");
            String fbgender=jsonObject.getString("gender");
            String fbName= jsonObject.getString("name");
            String fbLocation=jsonObject.getString("location");
            String fbid = jsonObject.getString("id");

            profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.NORMAL);
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(jsonObject.getString("id"));

            String propic = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbid+ "/picture?type=large";

            session.setFbLogin(fbid, fbName, propic, fbLocation, fbgender, fbemail);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in Session.java

```
 public class Session {
        private SharedPreferences sp;
        private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;


        public static final String KEY_FBUID ="Fbid";
        public static final String KEY_FBNAME ="Fbname";
        public static final String KEY_FBEMAIL="Fbemail";
        public static final String KEY_FBGEND ="Fbgend";
        public static final String KEY_FBPROPIC ="Fbpropic";
        public static final String KEY_FBLOCAT ="Fblocation";

        public Session(Context context) {
            sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        }



       public boolean setFblogin(boolean status){
            spEditor= sp.edit();
            spEditor.putBoolean("fb_logged_in",status);
            spEditor.commit();
            return true;
        }

        public void setFbLogin(String fid, String fname, String fpropic, String fulocation, String fbgend,String fbemail){

            spEditor.putString("Fbid",fid);
            spEditor.putString("Fbname",fname);
            spEditor.putString("Fbpropic",fpropic);
            spEditor.putString("Fblocation",fulocation);
            spEditor.putString("Fbgend",fbgend);
            spEditor.putString("Fbemail",fbemail);
            spEditor.commit();
        }


        public HashMap<String, String> getfbUserDetails(){
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // user name
            user.put(KEY_FBUID, sp.getString(KEY_FBUID, null));
            user.put(KEY_FBNAME, sp.getString(KEY_FBNAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_FBEMAIL, sp.getString(KEY_FBEMAIL, null));
            user.put(KEY_FBLOCAT, sp.getString(KEY_FBLOCAT, null));
            user.put(KEY_FBPROPIC, sp.getString(KEY_FBPROPIC, null));
            return user;
        }
```

in my main Activity i want want to use `getfbuserDetails()` and fetch the session stored values. but HashMap is not working.

please Comment if there is any doubt.

Comment: where is your shared preferences constructor being used?

Comment: You can store your graph data into json object and than store it in shared preference

Comment: `but HashMap is not working.` Is it showing any error? What does it mean by not working? Post your code of `MainActivity` also where you are fetching values

Comment: its working for 2 values but if i am trying to get more then 2 not working

Answer (score -1):

2 method

1.Save data Json format String not convert object. When get data before get   json(String) after convert json to object(use Gson)

2.Here https://github.com/pilgr/Paper